# Work done by the Lorentz force?

Tags: electromagnetism

Im trying to calculate the work done on a single wire placed inside a magnetic field. Now for the force I've used the Lorentz force formula to calculate it, for the distance should I used the width of the conductor, since the Lorentz force is only applied on that distance, is that correct?

Comment: Use right hand curl rule to determine the direction of magnetic force.

Comment: Using the width for distance works fine?

Comment: Yes , If the magnetic field is perpendicular to the plane of wire. Otherwise the electrons in the wire wont be deflected. If it is not perpendicular, use the perpendicular component of magnetic field.(You can google Hall Effect). Btw, it is a better question for physics stack exchange ; Plus I can recall that magnetic field does no work since it is always perpendicular to motion. So work will be done by only Electric field.

Comment: Which form of the Lorentz force are you using, can you add it to your question?